# Strange UITableView errors

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am making an app (my first, wow!) and I'm getting an error, that I just can't seem to fix when, I load a table view.

I have an initial ViewController that works just fine. I have a button that segues to a Navigation controller pointing to a UITableView. There appears to be a problem with my UITableView subclass's tableView:numberOfRowsInSection override.

Here is the code setting up the Table:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

When I load the Table View scene I get a "signalSIGABRT" error in the App delegate.

The error appears to be in the numberOfRowsInSection method, since when I comment it out, the error doesn't appear, and I just get an empty table.

In debugging, I set a breakpoint at the "return 2" line of that method, and it stops there without crashing. I haven't really progressed from there: I hit "Step Over" and it brings me to a screen that I'm definitely too new to all this to understand, full of lines like these:

```
UIKit`-[UITableView _numberOfRowsInSection:]:
    0x10641a23e <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10641a23f <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10641a242 <+4>:  pushq  %r15
    0x10641a244 <+6>:  pushq  %r14
    0x10641a246 <+8>:  pushq  %r12
    0x10641a248 <+10>: pushq  %rbx
    0x10641a249 <+11>: movq   %rdx, %r14
    0x10641a24c <+14>: movq   %rdi, %r15
    0x10641a24f <+17>: movq   0x101d2e2(%rip), %rdi     ; UITableView._dataSource
    0x10641a256 <+24>: addq   %r15, %rdi
    0x10641a259 <+27>: callq  0x106eca892               ; symbol stub for: objc_loadWeakRetained
    0x10641a25e <+32>: movq   %rax, %r12
    0x10641a261 <+35>: movq   0xfe3300(%rip), %rsi      ; "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:"
    0x10641a268 <+42>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x10641a26b <+45>: movq   %r15, %rdx
    0x10641a26e <+48>: movq   %r14, %rcx
    0x10641a271 <+51>: callq  *0xd0afe1(%rip)           ; (void *)0x00000001044f7ac0: objc_msgSend
->  0x10641a277 <+57>: movq   %rax, %rbx
    0x10641a27a <+60>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x10641a27d <+63>: callq  *0xd0afdd(%rip)           ; (void *)0x00000001044f4d20: objc_release
    0x10641a283 <+69>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10641a285 <+71>: testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x10641a288 <+74>: cmovsq %rax, %rbx
    0x10641a28c <+78>: movq   %rbx, %rax
    0x10641a28f <+81>: popq   %rbx
    0x10641a290 <+82>: popq   %r12
    0x10641a292 <+84>: popq   %r14
    0x10641a294 <+86>: popq   %r15
    0x10641a296 <+88>: popq   %rbp
    0x10641a297 <+89>: retq
```

And when I hit "Continue" it doesn't actually progress, which seems strange.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone has an idea to help.

Here's some background info that may or may not shed any light:
I'd originally written most of this app before updating it through XCode8 to Swift 3. I don't know what effect this had and unfortunately I forget whether I wrote this part of the app (that's causing problems) in Swift 3 or before.
I learned to code from Kevin McNeisch's "iOS App Development for Non-Programmers" book series, and had previously had my main Business Controllers in this app as subclasses of his mmBusinessObject. But Swift 3 broke mmBusinessObject so I changed those to NSManagedObjects and it all worked fine. I mean, I also haven't accessed any entity tables so far; and this problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with those parts of the app, but I figured I'd include the info anyway.

Thanks!
Jonathan

EDIT:
Apparently I'm such a n00b that I can't even figure out how to reply to the comments! (I hit "add a comment" and it brings me to the top of the page but nothing at all has changed on the page)

Thanks for the comments. In response:

About cellForRowAtIndexPath:
With numberOfSections, and numberOfRowsInSection, and cellForRowAtIndexPath, I get the error
With cellForRowAtIndexPath commented out (and the other two active), I get the error.
With numberOfRowsInSection commented out (and the other two active), I get an empty table.

About the delegate/datasource: 
My ViewController here is a subclass of UITableViewController so if I try to set it for datasource or delegate Protocol, it says it's redundant. In the storyboard view, the delegate and data source of the Table View are both set to "Browse Songs" which is the name of the tableview; if I select the yellow icon at the top of the scene, datasource and delegate are both listed as "Table View." These happened automatically (i.e., I didn't do it myself, it was just there), and I think it's what it's supposed to be?

About the ViewController: I'm guessing you mean this current one with the problem? Here's the code below. Remember that this is linked to a Table View created from a Navigation Controller. Also, when I create it (from the Object Library) simply as a Table View, the section/row methods work okay, but I get layout issues and I want navigation anyway.

```
import UIKit

class SongListViewController2: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

//    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        return 2
//    }

  // Error seems to be caused by numberOfRowsInSection method


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Does cellForRowAtIndexPath get called?

Comment: Please give us more info about you view controller. With some code ?

Comment: Did you connect the delegate and datasource?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Please see my responses to the comments in edits to my message above, including the full code of the ViewController in question.

Comment: My guess is that your data source (the SongListViewController2, supposedly) is suddenly ceasing to exist. But you have not given any info that should show why.

Comment: Where do you (re)load the table view?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't set `Identifier` in your table view cell like the image I attached. Check your storyboard. Ex. Table View -> Table View Cell

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you! It was a bit of a mystery because the error appeared to be elsewhere but that did it!

Comment: @JonathanTuzman: Note that you can *accept* an answer by clicking on the check mark. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.